# How to create an executable ESP-IDF Project on a local server

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, esp32, esp-idf

im trying to relocate my latest ESP-IDF project from my harddrive into my local server, so I can work on it on multiple devices.
Sadly i was facing some issues building the project. So I tried to create the example project "Hello World" on my local server and build it. Exactly the same console ouput pops out:

```
 Executing task: cmake -G Ninja -DPYTHON_DEPS_CHECKED=1 -DESP_PLATFORM=1 .. <

-- Found Git: C:/Users/user/.espressif/tools/idf-git/2.30.1/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.30.1.windows.1")
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/Users/user/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r1-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/user/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r1-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/user/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r1-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/user/.espressif/tools/cmake/3.16.4/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Users/user/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r1-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe"      

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: //192.168.0.10/projects/my_project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/user/.espressif/tools/ninja/1.10.2/ninja.exe cmTC_294a8 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_294a8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_294a8
    FAILED: cmTC_294a8
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\user\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r1-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address   CMakeFiles/cmTC_294a8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj  -o cmTC_294a8   && cd ."        
    "\\192.168.0.10/projects/my_project\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp"
    CMD.EXE wurde mit dem oben angegebenen Pfad als aktuellem Verzeichnis gestartet.
    UNC-Pfade werden nicht unterstützt.
    Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt.
    xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe: error: CMakeFiles/cmTC_294a8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj: No such file or directory
    xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/user/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:311 (__project)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "//192.168.0.10/projects/my_project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "//192.168.0.10/projects/my_project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command cmake -G Ninja -DPYTHON_DEPS_CHECKED=1 -DESP_PLATFORM=1 .." terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Searching for my problem lead me to similar threads, but sadly none of them were helping me.
Anyone experienced similar problems with a local server?

thanks in advance

Edit:
this might clearify my question even more. Here is my CMakeError.log:

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: //192.168.0.10/projects/my_project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/user/.espressif/tools/ninja/1.10.2/ninja.exe cmTC_294a8 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_294a8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_294a8

FAILED: cmTC_294a8 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\user\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r1-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address   CMakeFiles/cmTC_294a8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj  -o cmTC_294a8   && cd ."

"\\192.168.0.10\d\projects\my_project\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp"

CMD.EXE wurde mit dem oben angegebenen Pfad als aktuellem Verzeichnis gestartet.
#CMD.Exe was started from current directory with above stated Path

UNC-Pfade werden nicht unterstützt.
# UNC Path is not supported

Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt.
#instead windows-directory will be used as directory 

xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe: error: CMakeFiles/cmTC_294a8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj: No such file or directory
xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

for my english-speaking fellas... the German part is roughly translated 1 line below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to compile a project directly off a Windows network share? That's a marginal use case. I don't think there are many tools which support this, for the simple reason that *nobody* does such a thing. At the very least, mount the remote share as a drive in your computer.

I'd recommend creating a git repo, uploading your code there. That's a standard solution for sharing code.